# Delay() vs SetTimeOut() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**delay()** and **setTimeOut()** which one is efficient to use based on speed.

```
setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
```

and

```
$(selector).delay(speed,queueName)
```

as

```
speed Specifies the speed of the delay
Possible values:

milliseconds
"slow"
"fast"
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by efficient to use? (speed, memory usage etc...?)

Comment: delay is jQuery function and setTimeout Js function. *AVOID TO USE SUCH FUNCTION*

Comment: @GautamJha You don't need to 'avoid' anything. Both have valid use cases.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I completely agree these two are valid functions but  for me these functions made trouble in long run. specially DATA Validation / Fetch is always risky using these two.

Comment: Possibly, but that's not relevant here, and nor is it a good idea to make a blanket statement saying 'don't do X' when it has a completely valid purpose when used properly.

Comment: @NickParsons based on speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the think is that ,

1)  we use delay() in jQuery for effects like animations.

2) Secondly if we need to trigger an event after specific time , we can use setTimeout()

that's it...!!!